# Using FME to convert oracle sdo.geometry to SQL geometry datatype

Tags: oracle, ssis, type-conversion, gis, sqldatatypes

Hi I have to take the [sdo_geometry field from an Oracle database](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objrelschema.htm#i1004087) and transfer the data to a SQL database (probably [a geometry spatial data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx)). Could you help me on how to use FME for that purpose? Do I need FME to do this?

Comment: You can find a few good thoughts topic here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14797/using-arcgis-desktop-with-sql-server-spatial-as-backend

Answer (score 0):

FME will certainly help make things easier, but it's possible to do your data ETL without it. You'll need to handle each of the different OGS types yourself, if you want to get around having to use a tool that is aware of the geometric datatypes like FME.